# How to remove this id ( relationship ) using typeOrm in nest js

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

how to remove this `departmentId` means instead of this `id` set `null` that means this student never have any relation. so how to do it. i try many thing but i didn't imagine how to do it.

***student.controller.ts***

```
@Patch(':studentId/remove')
    delete(@Param('studentId') studentId : number){
            return this.studentService.removeDepartment(studentId);
    }
```

***student.service.ts***

```
async removeDepartment(id: number) {
    const student = await this.studentRepo.findOneBy({id})
if(!student){
    throw new NotFoundException('User Not found');
}
return this.studentRepo.remove(student);
  }
```

***student.entity.ts***

```
 @ManyToOne(()=>Department, (department)=>department.students,{onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
    department : Department
```

***department.entity.ts***

```
@OneToMany(()=>Student, (student)=>student.department,{onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
  students: Student[]
```

***Current***

[image]

***Expected :***
if we hit this `api`, in front of `departmentId` remove and set null.